# Read & Write on UART don't work

Tags: uart

I made a pair of programs to test UART function (GPIO 14 and 15 connected together). The read side works in a infinite loop and prints everything it got:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0")
while True:
    data=ser.read(1)
    print data
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

The write side feeds five characters, then exit:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0")
ser.write("abcde")
```

However, both programs just stuck and got nothing output.

My configuration is:

- raspberry Pi 3;
- GPIO 14 and 15 connected together;
- removed console declaration from `/boot/cmdline.txt`;
- added `enable_uart=1` into `/boot/config.txt`;
- no dtoverlay used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't `/dev/ttyAMA0` used for Bluetooth on the Raspberry Pi3?

You may need to use `/dev/ttyS0` or `/dev/serial1` on the Pi3 (check in `/boot/overlays/README`).